# How to activate code completion for TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, clrscode3e

I have downloaded `clrscode3e.sty` file and put it at the corresponding place, it works now. But TeXstudio auto completion fails. How does TeXstudio achieve auto completion? What can I do to enable auto completion for `clrscode3e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after trying for some while, I have worked out the way.

according to [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), go to the TeXstudio config directory:

`This directory is placed in ~/.config/texstudio under linux and usually "c:\Documents and Settings/User/AppData/Roaming/texstudio" under windows`

then go to sub directory `completion\autogenerated`, you can see lots of `cwl` files. open one with text editor. If you see some lines end with `#S`, this is the cause. If you are using linux, then a single line of `sed -i 's/#S$/#/g' *.cwl` should do the trick. If you are using windows, maybe you can checkout cmd scripts to find out how to do it.

according to my experience, either replacing `#S` with `#` or removing `#S` does the trick.

^_^

Answer (score 2):

You need a cwl-file which doesn't exist for `clrscode3e.sty` in current TeXstudio. `See Options->Configure TeXstudio->Auto completion`. You have to create an own one.

Comment: so how can I find cwl files for ``clrscode3e``?How can I create my own one?

Comment: On Ubuntu they are in `~/.config/texstudio/` and the own one in `~/.config/texstudio/complition/user/`

Comment: I have found the ``cwl`` generated by tex studio automatically, but it still can't do auto completion. I have seen the line ``\proc{arg1}#S`` at ``clrscode3e.cwl``, but when I include ``clrscode3e`` package and type ``\pro``, I can't see ``proc`` at the command list to be selected.

Comment: I have surprizingly found out that if I change the line ``\proc{arg1}#S`` to ``\proc{arg1}`` (namely, delete the ``#S``) or change it to ``\proc{arg1}#``, tex studio will do the auto completion now. Is it a bug of tex studio that it auto generates wrong cwl files?

Comment: @游凯超 Read “classification format” in the [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

Comment: @Troy thanks, I have already noticed the user manual, but it doesn't talk about how it deals with the ``#S`` that tex studio auto generates.

Comment: @游凯超 By default, #S is assigned for autogenerated cwl commands because there is no way for TXS to know what that command is supposed to represent. It is up to the user to write his/her own cwl for custom commands, and provide proper classification for them. The user manual does mention what #S means..

Comment: @Troy but this makes tex studio unable to do auto completion, which is really inconvinient for users. I just want to include a package and get code completion for its commands. Thinking that I have to write a cwl file to make the auto completion works, I'm terrified to include any packages.